# Java Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - fragment shader texture2D does not work

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem, if I try to render a textured quad, nothing appear on the screen.
A simple colored quad works great.
It seems that only if I use the "texture2D" function nothing works.
But I am not getting any error message if I compile the shaders or link the program.

This work (A red quad appear on the screen):

```
uniform sampler2D un_TextureUnit;

varying vec2 fr_UV;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

This does not work (Nothing appear on the screen):

```
uniform sampler2D un_TextureUnit;

varying vec2 fr_UV;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(un_TextureUnit, fr_UV);
}
```

This does not work (Nothing appear on the screen, too):

```
uniform sampler2D un_TextureUnit;

varying vec2 fr_UV;

void main()
{
    vec4 c = texture2D(un_TextureUnit, vec2(0.5, 0.5));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Note that I only changed to shader and nothing on the code.
Only If I use the "texture2D" function the shader seems not to compile, but I dont get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

My fragment shader works fine to draw texture on triangles:

```
 precision highp float;

 uniform sampler2D u_texture0;
 varying vec2 v_textureCoordinate0;  


 void main()                                  
 {                   
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture0, v_textureCoordinate0);
 }
```

So, i believe the problem isn't in your fragment shader (that is similar to mine), but in the code to prepare shader. I suggest you to check:

- if your code to bind texture is correct (check GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer, GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray)
- if there is any face culling

Anyway, [here](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/) there is a good tutorial to how to draw a triangle with texture.